# interacting with redis-client pod on kubernetes

Tags: python-2.7, kubernetes, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I'm having a Redis cluster on Kubernetes.

I need to interact with one of the redis-client pods, mainly in order to delete keys from time to time.

The way I'm currently doing it is:

1. Tunnel Kubernetes dashobard to localhost:8081
2. From the dashboard, doing exec into redis client pod
3. Running: `redis-cli -h redis-master -a mypassword`
4. Deleting the needed key, `del "*my_key_name*"`

I want to be able to do so from a local python script.
Using kubernetes for python I'm able to execute commands on redis-client pod:

```
    v1=client.CoreV1Api()
    exec_command = [
    '/bin/sh',
    '-c',
    'redis-cli -h redis-master -a mypassword']

    resp = stream(v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,"redis-client2-5889976c9b-nv99v", 'default',
              command=exec_command,
              stderr=True, stdin=False,
              stdout=True, tty=False)
```

My problem is, I can't execute commands in the context of redis-cli, i.e, I can connect to redis-cli but can't send commands to it (only to `/bin/sh`)

Is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the apparently the solution is pretty simple, I can pass parameters to the redis-cli tool to execute what I want, all in one command. so I did:

```
exec_command = [
'/bin/sh',
'-c',
'redis-cli -h redis-master -a mypassword del *my_key_name*']
```

and that is it